# Effectiveness of chlorine dioxide in fighting COVID-19

Tags: covid-19, sterilization

How effective would dissolving chlorine dioxide tablets in a bucket of water be for sterilizing a room from the Novel Coronavirus (COVID-19)? Would the vapors be enough?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chlorine dioxide is generally used for disinfection. In hospitals (where contamination rate is high) for disinfecting the surfaces,  2000 mg/L of chlorine dioxide is used, and for spraying 1000 mg/L of chlorine dioxide is used to disinfect the air. And at airports 250 - 500 mg/L chlorine dioxide is used for sterilization.

And vapors are not enough for sterilizing room, it works by applying that disinfecting solution onto the surfaces or by spraying into air. Check out this [link](https://quiplabs.com/product/mb-10-tablets/), to know how these chlorine dioxide tablets work.

[Chlorine dioxide can be hazardous to human health, so use it with utmost precautions](https://selfhacked.com/blog/chlorine-dioxide/).

**Reference:**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7159873/

https://www.iata.org/contentassets/7e8b4f8a2ff24bd5a6edcf380c641201/airport-preventing-spread-of-coronavirus-disease-2019.pdf

Comment: Also, https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1793959O/cleaning-and-disinfecting-3m-reusable-respirators-following-potential-exposure-to-coronaviruses.pdf provides information about equipment decontamination. However, I disagree with the use in the question and by yourself regarding the use of the term "sterilization" as this means something that is entirely unnecessary in this particular context. Even operating rooms are not actually "sterilized" between cases. Surgical instruments are.